# SQL Server : update trigger not between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making a SQL instead of update trigger so It is not possible to have more than 1 promotion for the same store with time overlap.

My trigger looks like this:

```
create or alter trigger instead_update_promotion
on GHOST_PROMOTIONS
instead of update
as 
begin
    update GHOST_PROMOTIONS 
    set IDSTORE = i.IDSTORE, 
        STARTDATE = i.STARTDATE, 
        ENDDATE = i.ENDDATE, 
        TYPEOFPROMOTION = i.TYPEOFPROMOTION,
        STARTINGPRICE = i.STARTINGPRICE,
        FINALPRICE = i.FINALPRICE,
        PRICEREDUCTIONPERDAY = i.PRICEREDUCTIONPERDAY
    from 
        inserted i, GHOST_PROMOTIONS p
    where 
        i.IDPROMOTION = p.IDPROMOTION
        and not (i.IDPROMOTION <> p.IDPROMOTION and i.IDSTORE = p.IDSTORE and (i.STARTDATE between p.STARTDATE and p.ENDDATE or i.ENDDATE between p.STARTDATE and p.ENDDATE))
end
```

Explaining my logic:

First: i.IDPROMOTION <> p.IDPROMOTION
-> so it doesn't compare with itself;

Second: i.IDSTORE = p.IDSTORE
-> we only care about time overlap in the same store;

Third: (i.STARTDATE between p.STARTDATE and p.ENDDATE or i.ENDDATE between p.STARTDATE and p.ENDDATE)
-> True if inserted date values are within a known date range

These 3 statements are written after a "and not" so if the 3 are True(meaning there exists a row different than itself with time overlap in the same store) it results in a False and the data isn't changed.

But this isn't working, it updated an overlapping date any idea why that is? Ty

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't want to do this in one statement.  It's harder; and you should fail the whole batch if any rows violate the rule.  So first check INSERTED against the target table, then update if no violations are found.  eg

```
create or alter trigger instead_update_promotion
on GHOST_PROMOTIONS
instead of update
as 
begin
    if exists (
    select *
    from inserted i, GHOST_PROMOTIONS p
    where i.IDPROMOTION <> p.IDPROMOTION 
      and i.IDSTORE = p.IDSTORE 
      and (i.STARTDATE between p.STARTDATE and p.ENDDATE or i.ENDDATE between p.STARTDATE and p.ENDDATE)
      )
      begin
         throw 51000, 'Cannont have overlapping promotions for the the same store', 1;
      end

      --update here
end
```